# 'stdx’ is not a namespace-name error being shown for a ptr_vector program

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces

I've been trying a program from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/ptr_vecto.aspx?bcsi_scan_18A7FE912C6AADB5=EuaJak4KoROBP3Fh2gAqV4VuR54KAAAAGGVlAQ==&bcsi_scan_filename=ptr_vecto.aspx), about ptr_vector, and while compiling, the above error is shown.
Googling shows no hope to solve this problem. Could anyone here help out?
Here's the entire code (am compiling with gcc 4.2.2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

using namespace std;    // for cout, endl, find, replace, ...
using namespace stdx;   // for ptr_vector, ptr_vector_owner
using namespace boost;

int main()
{
   cout << "---- ptr_vector demo ----" << endl;

   ptr_vector<string> ptv;
   ptr_vector_owner<string> owner (ptv);  // scope-guard: owner of new-ed objects

   ptv.push_back (new string ("Peter"));
   ptv.push_back (new string ("Paul"));
   ptv.insert    (ptv.end(), new string ("Margaret"));

   cout << " 1: " << ptv.front()  << " " << ptv.back() << endl;
   cout << " 2: " << ptv[1]       << " " << ptv.at(2)  << endl;
   cout << " 3: " << *ptv.begin() << " " << *(ptv.begin() + 1) << endl;

   cout << " 4:";
   for (ptr_vector<string>::iterator it = ptv.begin(); it != ptv.end(); ++it)
      cout << " " << *it;
   cout << endl;

   ptv.sort();
   cout << " 5: " << ptv[0] << " " << ptv[1] << " " << ptv[2] << endl;

   ptv.sort (greater<string>());
   cout << " 6: " << ptv[0] << " " << ptv[1] << " " << ptv[2] << endl;

   ptr_vector<string>::iterator iter;
   iter = find (ptv.begin(), ptv.end(), "Paul");
   if (iter != ptv.end())
      cout << " 7: " << *iter << endl;

   replace (ptv.begin(), ptv.end(), string ("Paul"), string ("Fred"));
   cout << " 8: " << ptv.begin()[1] << endl;

   string* str = ptv.pop_back();
   cout << " 9: " << *str <<  " - size: " << ptv.size() << endl;
   delete str;

   delete ptv.detach (ptv.begin());
   cout << "10: " << ptv[0] << " - size: " << ptv.size() << endl;

   ptr_vector<string> ptvTwo;
   ptr_vector_owner<string> ownerTwo (ptvTwo);

   ptvTwo.push_back (new string ("Elisabeth"));
   ptvTwo.push_back (new string ("Susan"));
   ptv.swap(ptvTwo);
   if (ptv < ptvTwo)
      cout << "11: " << *ptv.begin() << " - size: " << ptv.size() << endl;

   return 0;
}//main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdx` is not a standard namespace, it is defined by the particular implementation you are trying to use. You are not using the header file include `#include "ptr_vector.h"` inside which `namespace stdx` exists. Currently the `ptr_vector` you are using is being included from `boost` namespce. That begs the question, if you can use `boost` why do you want use `stdx` namespace solution.

Comment: Am not using ptr_vector.h because there is no such file in my system. So I'm using ptr_vector.hpp. Am I wrong to do so?

Comment: Yes, you need to download the source code from CodeProject.  Is this the only error you are getting? Is the compiler not complaining about class such as `ptr_vector_owner`? I suggest you to either use the `boost` solution (preferred) or use the `stdx` solution, don't mixup both.

Comment: Oh...ok. Thanks. I'll go with the boost solution. The error does show "‘ptr_vector_owner’ was not declared in this scope". Is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: @Nav: That class is not needed when using the `boost` solution. The `boost::ptr_vector` class will take care of deleting the pointed to objects itself.